# Calculating probability for multiple linear correlated events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, problem-solving

I'm struggling with establishing proper equation for calculating probability of occurrence N events (correlated with each other or not) in the list. I spent more than a month on it and can't find the proper one.

I have N events with probability of occurrence for every of them. For example:

- ()= 0.42
- ()= 0.42
- (C)= 0.52

I also have correlation matrix (Pearson Correlation) of those events, for example:

- = 0
- = 0.5
- = 0.5

All events in the list might be independent (correlation = 0) and dependent (correlation != 0) as well. Although those events will never be mutually exclusive or complementary.

I would like to find an equation which result will be equal to final probability of occurrence of all those events at once given the fact that if event A or B occurs then the event C is much more likely to happen.

For now I have tried to adapt the result from this thread [Probability of three events occurring given correlation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205928/probability-of-three-events-occurring-given-correlation) but it came out that it's harder than I thought as in the thread it's a 1-dimensional problem but in this case we have 2-dimensional.

It would be great if you'd help me with the equation or some suggestions/tips on how to tackle the problem (maybe there is other way) because I think I'm missing something here.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: There will be infinitely many solutions.  You can make a table of size $2^N$ with all the probabilities

Comment: @Mason Could you please clarify, why? I'm still thinking that If I have a linear correlation between events A and B, and have both of probabilities, then It should be doable to calculate probability of both events occurring.